# VBScript vs VB.NET, equal syntax?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, syntax, vbscript

Is the **syntax** for VBScript and VB.NET exactly the same?

Specifically, would a syntax parser for VB.NET work for VBScript?

Comment: I'm tempted to say, you *could* have tried and figured it out yourself pretty quickly!

Comment: Downvoter please comment, and also @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, There's actually no way to try **all** possibilities.

Comment: Why try all possibilities? It just takes one counterexample to show that they are not exactly the same.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, That comment's a [tiar](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqQnpHY3hSeTQ3WVk/tiar). And besides, that's the point of the question. To see if there's such a counterexample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, they are not the same.

vb.net is a jit-compiled strongly typed object oriented language that runs on the .net framework; vbscript is interpreted.  Syntax is different in many subtle ways, mostly relating to scoping and the keywords necessary for vb.net to support true object oriented concepts that vbscript just doesn't have.

Answer (score 6):

No, the syntax for VBScript is very similar to pre-.NET Visual Basic (i.e., VB6). VB.NET is completely different. But even compared to VB6, VBScript is still watered down.

Answer (score 4):

No, the syntax for vbscript and vb.net are not exactly the same.